# Matlab - access dynamically part of data structure

Tags: matlab

I have a **data structure A.B.C** and I want to access some of its parts dynamically reading the object names from a cell array populated by importing csv file.

```
For example, my data structure has following fields A.B.C
within B are B1, B2, B2, B3, B4, B5
within C are field_1, field_3, field_3
Names cell array with all the possibilities for B, imported from cvs
```

I want to **access dynamically field_2 for each B case**.
I imported the names from csv file and tried to pass the names like:

```
A.(Names(1,1)).field_2
```

but get an error

```
'Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.'
```

When I print the single names of the array the apostrophes are there. For example Names(1,1) returns 'B1' not B1

How can I bypass the apostrophes?
or is it a better way to reference the objects?

Comment: If `Names` is a cell array, you probably want to use `Names{1,1}` instead `Names(1,1)`. If you check in your MATLAB workspace, the latter is of data type cell array, whereas the former is of data type string array. I believe that's the source of your problem.

Comment: Both variants give error  A.Names{1,1}.field_2: Reference to non-existent field 'Names'.
A.(Names{1,1}).field_2: Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
I mported the csv using readtable(filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm building off of emzet's comment, and providing a reproducible example, showing how this will work. Here's my code to re-create your structure:

```
A = struct();
A.B1 = struct();
A.B2 = struct();
A.B3 = struct();
A.B4 = struct();
A.B1.field_1 = 'testB1C1';
A.B1.field_2 = 'testB1C2';
A.B1.field_3 = 'testB1C3';
A.B1.field_4 = 'testB1C4';
A.B2.field_1 = 'testB2C1';
A.B2.field_2 = 'testB2C2';
A.B2.field_3 = 'testB2C3';
A.B2.field_4 = 'testB2C4';
A.B3.field_1 = 'testB3C1';
A.B3.field_2 = 'testB3C2';
A.B3.field_3 = 'testB3C3';
A.B3.field_4 = 'testB3C4';

NamesB = {'B1', 'B2', 'B3' ,'B4'};
NamesC = {'field_1', 'field_2', 'field_3' ,'field_4'};
```

Now, as you've indicated, doing this:

```
A.(NamesB(1)).(NamesC{1})
```

will return an error:

```
Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.
```

If you do this, instead:

```
A.(NamesB{1}).(NamesC{1}) % notice the curly braces after NamesB.

ans =

'testB1C1'
```

will provide the right value.

Comment: I have spent some more time on it and tried to insert the list of Names directly in Matlab, the exact way you demonstrated and it worked! It seems that the problem relates to the inserting the list using csv. I initially created the Names using the function readtable(filename). Have you tried to insert the list using csv? Did it work for you either?

Comment: @emzet: I think I know where the problem is. I created a test csv file, with only the first column filled out, with rows containing (1) B_name (2) B1 (3) B2 (4) B3 (5) B4. and then imported it into MATLAB like so : `names = readtable('test.csv');`. Now, what MATLAB did was it renamed the row to be something like `x___B_name`. Now, I can access the character vector 'B1' using `names.x__B_name{1}`. This can replace `NamesB{1}` in the answer above. I hope this helps!